# Unity2D: What is the best way to implement my game background?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, memory-management, background

I want to know what is the best way to implement my game background into my game. My game is a 2d top down shooting game on mobile, so I was wonder if I should draw my background normally and implement it into my game or should I draw tiles and use unity tile map to implement it into my game? Which method would save memory on mobile and easy to implement into my game? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd do:

```
void Update () {
    this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetTextureOffset("_MainTex") + new Vector2(0.0f,speed));
}
```

I would have this monobehaviour attached to my background plane, with a top-down matching texture over a material, in a way that you can scroll your texture and it still would match. Also, this is the most memory efficient, it only depends on the texture resolution.

Comment: Thank you for answering back, just to be clear should I draw a full background picture on Photoshop or should I make small tiles on Photoshop. Because I only have one level for now and in the future I will be creating more levels with different backgrounds, so I wanted to know should I attach that script to a full background picture or attach it to tiles. Also what do you mean by texture, because I'll be drawing my background by hand. Thank you again for helping! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I will explain myself:

You should draw a full background picture on Photoshop for each level, but the important point is to match the top with the down border, in a way that you will be able to scroll your texture offset with the code of my answer and it will always look uniform.

The script should be attached to a Plane GameObject with the background texture on his material. The background will cover the full background plane, not only tiles (although with tiles it should work too).

Look this tuto
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ds9xhYHndXI. Then add my code to the background plane.